# Ford Taurus 01 shock holder problem

Tags: suspension, parts, shock-absorber

My car was making scratchy metal noise when turning left coming from the back. I checked the bottom of the car and found the issue. I don't fully know how to address it what the part's name is and if it's safe to drive. 
There is a stick coming from the shocks that is suppose to attach to some metal frame. 
I attached the pictures? I hope it is an easy fix and diy.

[image]

Above pic. is the faulty part and is missing some type of a bolt. It's back driver's side.

[image]

This one is the good one. It's on the back passenger side.

Do you think I can replace it on the go or do I need to put down the shocks first. Is this more work for a repair shop? I'd like to do it myself as long as I don't need to put down the shocks as I don't have proper tools for it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a relatively easy repair, as long as you have the tools to do it. The part you are looking for is called the sway bar (or stabilizer bar) bushings and links. You'll want to get a complete set of them (eight bushing halves, two link rods, two nuts, two sleeves and eight washers). As an example, you can get a set of these from RockAuto.com for under $10.

You can drive with it this way, but I wouldn't do it much. If you need to use the car to take it down to the parts house to get the parts, then it shouldn't be an issue. Plan to get this done as soon as possible, though. Your steering stability is affected by not having this in place.

Here's an image of the parts set you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: now when I'm looking at this set. It looks little different.

Comment: @Grasper ... Yes, this is not the stock set, but an OEM equivalent. Believe me when I say, this will work just fine for you. Many sets have two nuts for each rod, with a rod, not a bolt like this has. Either way will work just fine.

Comment: I got it fixed by professional, it cost me $60. Not bad.

Comment: @Grasper You could have easily done it yourself with basic hand tools ... but $60 is a good price. Hardly even the price of labor. I'm pleased it's fixed :D